# Angular Universal (SSR) Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory

Tags: angular, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, angular-universal

I want to deploy my angular universal app on aws.

From my understanding, I can only deploy my app on elastic beanstalk because it needs a web server to run. (It means no S3 deployment).

When I deploy my app, I have the following error:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory
>   "/var/app/current/dist/browser"
>       at Function.render (/var/app/current/server.js:122227:17)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/var/app/current/server.js:131120:7)
>       at /var/app/current/server.js:138:9
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/app/current/server.js:124007:5)
>       at next (/var/app/current/server.js:123755:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/var/app/current/server.js:123730:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/app/current/server.js:124007:5)
>       at /var/app/current/server.js:123230:22
>       at param (/var/app/current/server.js:123303:14)
>       at param (/var/app/current/server.js:123314:14)

Here what I've done so far:

1. On my angular project, create a production build with the command `npm run build:ssr`
2. Create an archive of my dist directory
3. On Elastic Beanstalk, create a new application with node.js and upload my archive

And my `server.ts` file:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found the solution to deploy on Elastic Beanstalk.

Below the different steps I did:

1. In your **Elastic Beanstalk Application**, edit the `Software Configuration` by changing the Node command by `node dist/server.js` [image: Software Configuration]
2. Edit the port used by nodejs (2 options) :

   a. You can simply edit the port in your `server.ts` file by **8081** (corresponding to the nodejs port used in the nginx default configuration)

   ```
   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;
   ```

   b. **OR** you can edit your nginx configuration with a [configuration file .ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to match the port used in your angular universal app (4000 by default)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `dist` folder as your archive instead of the contents of the `dist` folder.

Set the following 'node command' setting in your elastic beanstalk configuration.

```
node dist/server
```

This should allow you to run locally and on AWS EB with the standard Angular out of the box setup.

**EDIT**
Just to give a little more info, this should fix the problem. As pointed out by @Kartik Chandra the problem is in the **server.ts** file on line

```
const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/landing/browser');
```

When deploying on your prod env process will look for the **dist** folder, so if you do not copy it it will fail.

Options are to copy the entiry dist folder or changing your server.ts, however this will break your local development.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
```

write:

```
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'rootpathofServer/dist/browser');
```

**Example**:

```
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'root/www/prod/myProject/dist/browser');
```

*root/www/prod/myProject/dist/browser*

The above line refer to the path of my project (build path) from root in **nginx aws directory**.

And if not working, just console the CWD:

```
console.log('processPath',process.cwd());
```

In my case it return 
/ 
only,
so complete path is like 
/root/www/prod/myProject/dist/browser, 
which is ('/' + 'root/www/prod/myProject/dist/browser')
for this above example.

*Yeah it is also true nginx root directory is different from local i.e y it works locally fine and give error on server after deployment*.

It took days to sort this issue, I hope it will help you out.
The main problem is simple: it is not able to get index file at particular location or directory.
**#LearningNeverEnds**

Answer (score 1):

In my case it failed due to my i18n setup:
Instead of looking for files in `dist/APP_NAME/browser` the server should look for files in `dist/APP_NAME/browser`.

As described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60672309/11277795), I fixed this by:

- Updating my `server.ts` to add a language:

```js
//...
export function app(language) { //add language here
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/APP_NAME/browser', language); //Use language here


//...

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 5006;
  const language = process.env.LANGUAGE || 'fr';

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app(language); //Use the language here
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port} for language ${language}`);
    });
```

- Updating my package.json

```json
"serve:ssr": "env LANGUAGE=en node dist/APP_NAME/server/en/main.js",
```

Comment: If on Windows, separate commands with `&`, e.g. `env LANGUAGE=EN & node dist/APP_NAME/server/en/main.js`.  Then watch out for stray spaces coming in.  You may need to do `process.env.LANGUAGE?.trim()`.

Comment: Instead of looking for files in dist/APP_NAME/browser the server should look for files in dist/APP_NAME/browser. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

That bug is caused by the script not using the right folder for the index file. `__dirname` is a better way to get file path relative to the location of your `main.js`.

You can replace this line `const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), "dist/browser");`

with

`const distFolder = join(__dirname, "../../dist/browser");`