# When trying to run angular using ssr got an localize error

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to serve the angular code using this command `npm run serve:ssr`.

Getting the following error,

```
     throw new Error('It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.\n' +
        ^

Error: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.
Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.
(For non-CLI projects, add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `polyfills.ts` file.
For server-side rendering applications add the import to your `main.server.ts` file.)
    at _global.$localize (/Users/jawad/Documents/jawad/truedealsweb/dist/server.js:68040:15)
    at Module../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm2015/ng-bootstrap.js (/Users/jawad/Documents/jawad/truedealsweb/dist/server/main.js:134281:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jawad/Documents/jawad/truedealsweb/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
    at Object../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.ngfactory.js (/Users/jawad/Documents/jawad/truedealsweb/dist/server/main.js:148309:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jawad/Documents/jawad/truedealsweb/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
    at Object../src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory.js (/Users/jawad/Documents/jawad/truedealsweb/dist/server/main.js:275302:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jawad/Documents/jawad/truedealsweb/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
    at Object../src/main.server.ts (/Users/jawad/Documents/jawad/truedealsweb/dist/server/main.js:294702:37)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jawad/Documents/jawad/truedealsweb/dist/server/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.0 (/Users/jawad/Documents/jawad/truedealsweb/dist/server/main.js:294731:18)
```

Also I have add the @angular/localize in polyfills.ts but still getting same error.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640524/angular-9-using-angular-i18n-along-with-server-side-rendering-angular-universa

Comment: But I don't use i18n in a project

Comment: How did you add ssr? `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`?